# Is there a way to use variables in vba to identify MS-Access report fields?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am not a programmer, but have been tasked with doing this anyway!  We are working on a research project that involves testing properties of different samples.  I am trying to create a form that will generate a custom report based on what the user chooses.  So, I have multiple text boxes and check boxes to allow the user to define the query parameters (e.g. composition of the sample must contain at least 5% component A) and choose what data they are interested in seeing in said report (e.g. show pH, color, but not melting point).  I have successfully created code to generate the query, then generate a report based on that query, but the report defaults to column widths that are generally too big (for example, the pH column width is 3 inches, it only needs to be about 1).  I would like to be able to fix this, but have not been able to figure out how.  At the same time, some of these fields contain numbers that are averages of multiple test results, so I would like to limit the number of digits shown, and display them as % where appropriate.  I started with just fixing the column width issue:

I have tried to make a collection of the fields that are included, then loop through the collection and set column widths, but cannot figure out how to identify a field with a variable:

If I know the field name I can do this:

```
Reports("ReportName")!FieldID.Width = 200
```

But if I have a collection of names, FieldNames, or a string VariableName, none of these work, giving me an error that FieldNames or VariableName is not a valid field in the report:

```
Reports("ReportName")!FieldNames(1).Width = 200
Reports("ReportName")![FieldNames(1)].Width = 200
Reports("ReportName")![VariableName].Width = 200
```

Is there a way to reference a field name with a variable?

Alternatively, I thought there might be a way to loop through all fields and set widths - this would involve looking up a column width for each field, which I thought to do by adding a key to a collection of column widths.  But I cannot find a way to do that, something like:

```
For each Field in Reports("Report")
  Field.Width = ColumnWidthCollection(Field)
Next
```

This hangs up on the Field.Width line, with "invalid procedure call or argument", which brings me back to how to reference a field name with a variable.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
Reports("ReportName")(VariableName).Width = 200
```